# Convert Number to int? incompatible types found : void required: int

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-maps

I am writing an application to get latitude, longitude of a position in a google map using java and javascript.

The below code part gives an error:

### **code(It's a part of a jsp file):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

  //Initialization & some more code goes here

  function centerChanged() {
    <%
        int lat=0,lng=0;
        lat=%>map.getCenter().lat();<%
        lng=%>map.getCenter().lng();<%
        //request.setAttribute("lat", lat);
        //request.setAttribute("lng", lng);
    %>    
  }
```

From the above code, these are the two lines that cause the error:

> ```
>     lat=%>map.getCenter().lat();<%
>     lng=%>map.getCenter().lng();<%
> ```

### **Additional Information:**

`map.getCenter().lat()`  <<   This will return a Number as mentioned in [google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html):

### **This is the error I am getting:**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 81 in the jsp file: /maptest.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///maptest_jsp.java:127:
>   incompatible types found   : void required: int
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 82 in the jsp file: /maptest.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///maptest_jsp.java:130:
>   incompatible types found   : void required: int

Can anyone please tell what is wrong?

Comment: Could you give us a more detailed picture of what your JSP code looks like? Are `lat` and `lng` Java variables or JavaScript variables?

Comment: I'm new to posting; So please mention if I need to add more information/code.

Comment: If `lat` and `lng` are supposed to be Java/JSP variables and `map.getCenter().lat();` is JavaScript code then, the posted code **can not work**: JavaScript is executed *one the client* and *after* the JSP code is executed *on the server*. So you **can't** assign a JS value to a Java/JSP variable this way.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I see. Thanks! So, to get `map.getCenter().lat()` value to a java variable(`int lat`), should I declare `map` as a java variable(not a javascript variable)? Can that be a solution?

Comment: no, because the Google Maps API *always* runs on the client. *If* you need that information back at the server, then you'll need to get it back somehow (using a AJAX request or something similar).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Thanks a lot! I am new to AJAX but I will try your way and I will post any progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to dynamically insert a value from Javascript into JSP. The mistake is that JSP is executed on the server side, whilst Javascript on client side.

What you wrote there is equal to Java code:

```
out.write("function centerChanged() {");
int lat=0,lng=0;
lat=;
out.write("map.getCenter().lat();");
lng=;
out.write("map.getCenter().lng();");
//request.setAttribute("lat", lat);
//request.setAttribute("lng", lng);
out.write("}");
```

Get it? Whatever is surrounded by <%%> is pure Java code, whatever is outside of it, is printed out, hence your exception.

To work around it, you need to change the logic how you retrieve the client-side Javascript values in your server-side JSP code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am curious to figure out what you are trying to say. But one problem; Are you sure that the statements `lat=;` & `lng=;` are syntactically correct? They show some errors when I inserted them into a java file.

Comment: You can use Java. But you have to pass these variables differently, not this way.

Comment: Since I want the variables, `lat` & `lng`, to get updated **dynamically**, I think I **cannot use java**. Am I correct? (Because they are only executed once by the server)

Comment: lat=; and lng=; *are* the bits that throw exceptions for you. I never said that your code _should be_ like that. For dynamic execution of your scriptlet/servlet without having to reload the page on the client side, you have to use AJAX.

Comment: Okay, got it! What you have given is the java code which is generated from the jsp file to show me the error, right? Clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to get the latitude and longitude which is in double(data type) format, then downcast it to integer.

```
int xTemp = (int) (tempLatitude);

int yTemp = (int) (tempLong);
```

and to set center you can use-

```
map.setCenter(); method.
```

Hope I understood your question well.